# Appending a DOM element twice (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

Can someone explain why the following snippet does not add `<foo>` to both `#a` and `#b`?

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var $foo = $("<foo>HI</foo>");
    $("#a").append($foo);
    $("#b").append($foo);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parsa28/sCvs7/)

Edit: thanks for the helpful points, the fact that `.append()` moves the element explains this behavior. Since the element in my application is actually a Backbone View's `.el`, I prefer not to clone it.

Comment: If the element is already present in the DOM, append() just moves it. That's why on the second append the element is just moved from #a to #b.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because using `append` actually moves the element. So your code was moving `$foo` into the document at `#a`, then moving it from `#a` to `#b`. You could clone it instead like this for your desired affect - this way it is appending a clone rather than the initial element:

```
$(function(){
    var $foo = $("<foo>HI</foo>");
    $("#a").append($foo.clone());
    $("#b").append($foo.clone());
});
```

You could also append the `html` from `$foo`, which would just take a copy of the dom within it rather than the element itself:

```
$(function(){
    var $foo = $("<foo>HI</foo>");
    $("#a").append($foo[0].outerHTML);
    $("#b").append($foo[0].outerHTML);
});
```

The above examples are assuming you have a more complicated scenario where `$foo` isn't just a jQuery object created from a string... more likely it is created from an element in your DOM.

If it is in fact just simply created this way and for this purpose... there is no reason at all to create that jQuery object to begin with, you could simply append the string itself (`"<foo>HI</foo>"`) directly, like:

```
var foo = "<foo>HI</foo>";
$("#a").append(foo);
//...
```

Comment: @Radmation, you probably have another issue, check your console and if that doesn't help... ask a new question with all relevant info

Answer (score 12):

Try `clone`. This, as the name implies, will copy the `$foo` element and not move, like `append` will do.

```
$(function(){
    var $foo = $("<foo>HI</foo>");
    $("#a").append($foo.clone());
    $("#b").append($foo.clone());
});
```

But, why not just use this?

```
$("#a,#b").append($foo);
```

This will also work :)

Here's a demo for both these situations : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/sCvs7/3/

Answer (score 9):

You need to `create a new instance` every single time you want to append to the **DOM**.

Otherwise it refers to the same instance which was already appended.

Remove the `$` symbol preceding the new div to be added as that evaluates to a jQuery object and has the limitations as above stated. or `clone` the element.

```
$(function(){
    var foo = "<foo>HI</foo>";
    $("#a").append(foo);
    $("#b").append(foo);
});
```

[**Check Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sCvs7/2/)

Comment: To make your point more explicit, I would suggest removing the `$` prefix from the `foo` variable also, since it now contains a string instead of a jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the .clone() method to create a new instance to append to the DOM, since your current code just refers to the same instance twice.

```
$(function(){
    var $foo = $("<foo>HI</foo>");
    var $foo2 = foo.clone();
    $("#a").append($foo);
    $("#b").append($foo2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a trick and it worked. I just nested the function of one button click in another.
i mean I am changing the parent every time to avoid this issue. the main thing is that when i am writing the click function for button1 click the button2 logic is written under that and the button3 click logic is written inside button2 click method like a hierarchy. Just see the code. you will get it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>DOM Element Inserting!</h1>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="result">
        <button id="btn1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Start Cooking
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="parent2"></div>
    <div id="parent3"></div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
          $("#lt").remove();
          $("#parent2").html(`

                <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        Being Prepared
      </button>
                `);
          $("#btn1").remove();
          $("#btn2").click(function () {
            $("#parent3").html(`

                <button id="btn3" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
        Order Ready
      </button>
                `);
            $("#parent2").remove();
            $("#btn3").click(function () {
              alert("Order Completed!!");
            });
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question, which is 7 years old by the way.

Comment: Its just an alternate..to make the page behave like the same...if u get any other way to do so..share it..