# Append element ,getting append twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
$('label[id="p-n-from"]').on('click',function() {
    var fromele = $('<div id="p-n-from-'+ifrom+'" class="input-control text"  data-role="input"><span class="mif-location prepend-icon"></span><input id="from['+ifrom+']" placeholder =" Enter Pick Up Location"  type="text" required></div>');
    $(fromDiv).append(fromele);
    return false;           
 });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 ">
  <label class="input-control ">From</label>
  <div id="from-div">
    <div id="p-n-from-1" class="input-control text" data-role="input">
      <span class="mif-location prepend-icon"></span>
      <input id="from[0]" placeholder="Enter pickup " type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="" class="col-md-6 ">
    <label id="p-n-from" class="input-control">
      <button class="button mini-button cycle-button mif-plus fg-green"></button>Add More</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ">
  <div id="to-div">
    <label class="input-control ">To</label>
    <div id="p-n-to-1" class="input-control text" data-role="input">
      <span class="mif-location prepend-icon"></span>
      <input id="to[0]" placeholder="Enter drop location" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is simple script is adding the input box twice, although the most of the form has dynamically added elements.

I can't figure out why this one is getting added twice. I have tried suggestions from this [Appending a DOM element twice (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683549/appending-a-dom-element-twice-jquery)

But it didn't help. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML also ?

Comment: Can you check if handler is getting called twice?

Comment: @RohitArora added html

Comment: I created this fiddle which worked fine....can you replicate the same issue in this fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/6a87ujyd/

Comment: Yes , that's why I didn't put jsfiddle here . The problem might have happened because a number of handles were there on the whole page . I tried unbind. That helped .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a div only add the `inputs`, try this:

1 - Add a div in your html

```
<div id='IdYourDiv'></div>
```

2 - Configure the script

```js
var fromele = "<input type='text' id='input1'/><br><input type='text' id='input2'/>";
$('#IdYourDiv').html(fromele);
```

Comment: This is really strange  , I used your code .But anything I add to the "from-div" gets added twice . I am fixing with by different way . but I want to know whats wrong with the code .

Comment: I think very strange too. But a thing that I thought was in which moments do you call this function? Try call only the document.ready in moment for see the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label[id="p-n-from"]).unbind();
```

putting it before the trigger helped .

Comment: If this helps, check how you are binding event to it. Probably you are binding it more than once.

Comment: Tried that , it's bind just once.

Comment: There are only few options to check. Either there are more than one element, or event is getting bind more than once. Look for function that binds event to element, is it being called more than once.